# Modify all text output by TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I would like to create a "cleanup" extension that replaces various characters (quotes by guillemets) in all kinds of textfields in TYPO3.

I thought about extending `<f:format.html>` or `parseFunc`, but I don't know where to "plug in" so I get to replace output content easily before it's cached.

Any ideas, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind regexing, try this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['cleanUpQuotes'][] = \NAMESPACE\Your\Extension::class;
```

Insert it into ext_localconf.php and this part is done.
The next step is the class itself:

```
public function cleanUpQuotes(TypoScriptFrontendController $parentObject)
{
   $parentObject->content = DO_YOUR_THING_HERE        
}
```

Comment: I think I got it; edited your real-life example according to question. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find the hook 'cleanUpQuotes' in 8.7.8 source. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That's just a placeholder for your custom class / method

Answer (score 2):

There also is another possibility which could replace any strings in the whole page - as it operates on the rendered page (and not only on single fields).
You even can use regular expressions.

Look at my answer [-> here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557898/searching-for-typo3-extension-global-variables/47567284#47567284)

Comment: Wow, crazy! All built in! So stdWrap.replacement https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html could be also used on individual CEs, I guess?

Comment: You could use this replacement, where ever you can use `stdWrap`. As you can use it in a typoscript `lib.yourname` stub, you even can use it as `cObject` viewhelper in fluid.